# Turning a multiple If statement formula into VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I currently have the following formula inside a column of cells but as you can see its large and messy and I am afraid that the cells might get edited by someone working in the workbook accidentally.

So I have tried to code it in VBA but I keep getting a `Run-Time Error '91'`.  And I am stuck as to what I need to adjust to make it operate.

thanks for your help

Current Formula

`=IF(B7=$H$5,"1",IF(B7=$H$6,".75",IF(B7=$H$7,".75",IF(B7=$H$8,"1",IF(B7=$H$9,"1",IF(B7=$H$10,"1",IF(B7=$H$11,".5",IF(B7=$H$12,".5",IF(B7=$H$13,".5",IF(B7=$H$14,".5",IF(B7=$H$15,"1",IF(B7=$H$16,".75",IF(B7=$H$17,"1",IF(B7=$H$18,"1",IF(B7=$H$19,".75",IF(B7=$H$20,"1",IF(B7=$H$21,"1",IF(B7=$H$22,"1",IF(B7=$H$23,"1",IF(B7=$H$24,".75",IF(B7=$H$25,"1",IF(B7=$H$26,".75",IF(B7=$H$27,".5",IF(B7=$H$28,"1",IF(B7=$H$29,".75",IF(B7=$H$30,".5",IF(B7=$H$31,"1",IF(B7=$H$32,"1",IF(B7=$H$33,"1",IF(B7=$H$34,".5",IF(B7=$H$35,"1",IF(B7=$H$36,".25",IF(B7=$H$37,"1",IF(B7=$H$38,"1",IF(B7=$H$39,"1",IF(B7=$H$40,"1",IF(B7=$H$41,"1",IF(B7=$H$42,"1",IF(B7=$H$43,"1",IF(B7=$H$44,"1",IF(B7=$H$45,"1",IF(B7=$H$46,"1",IF(B7=$H$47,"1",IF(B7=$H$48,"1",IF(B7=$H$49,"1",IF(B7=$H$50,".5",IF(B7=$H$51,"1",IF(B7=$H$52,".25",IF(B7=$H$53,"1",IF(B7=$H$54,".75",IF(B7=$H$55,"1",IF(B7=$H$56,"1",IF(B7=$H$57,"1")))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))`

My attempt at turning it into VBA code

```
Sub Macro()
Dim Whole as long
Dim Third as long
Dim half as long
Dim quarter as long
Dim lookat as range
Dim answer as range

Whole = 1
third = .75
Half = .5
Quarter = .25

Lookat = Worksheets("sheet1".Range("B2:B300")
Answer = worksheets("Sheet1").range("C2:C300")

If Lookat = "AAAA" Or "AAAB" Or "AAAC" Or "AAAD" Or "AAAE" Or "AAAF" Or "AAAG" Or "AAAH" Or "AAAI" Or "AAAJ" Or "AAAK" Or "AAAL" Or "AAAM" Or "AAAN" Or "AAAO" Or "AAAP" Or "AAAQ" Or "AAAR" Or "AAAS" Or "AAAT" Or "AAAU" Or "AAAV" _
Or "AAAW" Or "AAAX" Or "AAAY" Or "AAAZ" Or "BBBA" Or "BBBB" Or "BBBC" Or "BBBD" Or "BBBE" Or "BBBF" Or "BBBG" Then
Answer.value=whole
ElseIf Lookat = "AAA" Or "AAB" Or "AAC" Or "AAD" Or "AAE" Or "AAF" Or "AAG" Or "AAH" Then
Answer.Value = Third
ElseIf Lookat = "AA" Or "AB" Or "AC" Or "AD" Or "AE" Or "AF" Or "AG" Or "AH" Then
Answer.Value = Half
ElseIf Lookat = "A" Or "B" Then
Answer.Value = Quarter    
end if
End Sub
```

Comment: BirdsView: Change all `Long` to `Double`. Use `Set` to assign your worksheets. You can't use `Lookat = "AAAA" Or "AAAB"`... as Lookat has more than 1 cell. Also missing a bracket after "sheet1"

Comment: To elaborate on what pnuts said, Put all of the values (the 1,.5,.75's) in `H5:H57` then the formula can be `=VLOOKUP(B7,H5:I57,2,FALSE)` and it will return the results you want, this also makes it MUCH easier to update in the future.

Comment: Looking at your VBA, (And this could be wrong) but you could always make the formula `=Len(B7)/4` if the value in `B7` will ALWAYS be one of your values. Seeing as how niether your VBA or your formula has anything to handle when the Value in `B7` is not one of your values anyways.

Comment: I will have to look into the Vlookup as it seems that is the concensus as to how to solve this problem.  My endstate was to have no fomula in the cell so that there is no way someone could edit the cell value from the worksheet.

Comment: you can still edit a value of a cell that is entered form vba, and the same way you would lock the cell value from being edited will also stop a formula from being edited. Besides after using the formula you could select the whole column, right click copy, right click paste special Values. To get rid of the formula, Formulas will be much faster then VBA when working from the worksheet atleast 99% of the time if not always.

Comment: Ok I will stick with the Vlookup on a hidden sheet I think that was an excelent solution.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 Protect your Workbook [Link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/password-protect-worksheet-or-workbook-elements-HP010078580.aspx) or hide it in a worksheet

2 Create your DataBase (your 'H' column)

3 In 'I' Column put your Weight [whole, third, half, quarter]. Sample:

```
+---------+--------+
| COL 'H' | HEIGHT |
+---------+--------+
|       6 | 1      |
|       9 | 0,5    |
|       4 | 0,75   |
|       6 | 1      |
|       8 | 0,5    |
|       1 | 0,75   |
|       5 | 1      |
|       4 | 0,5    |
|       5 | 0,75   |
|       7 | 1      |
|       4 | 0,5    |
|       9 | 0,75   |
|       1 | 1      |
|       8 | 0,5    |
|       1 | 0,75   |
|       5 | 1      |
|       1 | 0,5    |
|       4 | 0,75   |
|       4 | 1      |
|       1 | 0,5    |
|       7 | 0,75   |
+---------+--------+
```

4 Change your current formula to:

```
=VLOOKUP(B8,H:I,2,FALSE)
```

PS: You can try to name your Database to make your code better to understand [Link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-HA010147120.aspx).

Comment: @pnuts I just add random numbers to create this fake db. But the algorithm works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may suit:

```
+----+-----+------+
|    |  A  |  B   |
+----+-----+------+
|  1 | H10 | 1    |
|  2 | H14 | 0.5  |
|  3 | H15 | 1    |
|  4 | H16 | 0.75 |
|  5 | H18 | 1    |
|  6 | H19 | 0.75 |
|  7 | H23 | 1    |
|  8 | H24 | 0.75 |
|  9 | H25 | 1    |
| 10 | H26 | 0.75 |
| 11 | H27 | 0.5  |
| 12 | H28 | 1    |
| 13 | H29 | 0.75 |
| 14 | H30 | 0.5  |
| 15 | H33 | 1    |
| 16 | H34 | 0.5  |
| 17 | H35 | 1    |
| 18 | H36 | 0.25 |
| 19 | H49 | 1    |
| 20 | H5  | 1    |
| 21 | H50 | 0.5  |
| 22 | H51 | 1    |
| 23 | H52 | 0.25 |
| 24 | H53 | 1    |
| 25 | H54 | 0.75 |
| 26 | H57 | 1    |
| 27 | H7  | 0.75 |
+----+-----+------+
```

located in a sheet on its own in the same workbook and the array named say `Vt` of Workbook Scope.

This might then be used as the lookup table with a formula such as:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Vt,2)
```

where A1 contains a value such as "H10" for the purposes of this example.

It is important to sort A:B of the 'other' (to-be-hidden/protected) sheet in ascending order of ColumnA if to take advantage of a table that does not specifically equate every possible value. The lack of a fourth parameter in the VLOOKUP formula (though often causing problems!) means that an approximate match will be found where there is no exact match.