# IF formula #Value! Error (imbedded formula)

Tags: excel

```
=IF(OR(F16<=$H$4,F16>=$H$5),$H$2),IF(AND(F16>$I$4,F16<$I$5),$I$2),IF((F16>=$J$4),$J$2)
```

^I've been fiddling with this formula for hours on end and cannot fix it. I've replaced the value of H2 I2 and J2 with "words" and have also used different imbedded formulas. If anyone can help me that would be great. I am trying to make it so certain values within certain percentage ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In nested IF formulae it may help to expect as many closing parentheses at the end as IF statements. An (extreme!) example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21613230/turning-a-multiple-if-statement-formula-into-vba/21615001#21615001).

It is difficult to 'fix' a formula that does not work without knowing what is required of it and though @Pops has managed correct syntax I doubt it is the answer you want as you mention three possible outcomes and Pops only provides for two. I also doubt that your limits (`>=`, `<=` etc) are set correctly and question the use of OR here.

The syntax for an [IF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/if-HP005209118.aspx) statement is:

> IF(logical_test,value_if_true,value_if_false)

This is about correct for the last part of your formula `IF((F16>=$J$4),$J$2)` but leaves the parts before without closing parentheses.

A [VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) may be a simpler alternative which avoids the complexities of nested IFs and can be easier to update, if required.

Put the lower limits of your ranges from J4:L5 in a column immediately to the left of the labels to be shown (ie next to the values in Row2). I do not know which labels represent which range of values so for illustration have merely speculated.

The array created may be named, say `vScore`, with workbook scope so could be placed on a different sheet in the same workbook to keep it out of the way.

Then a much simpler formula such as `=VLOOKUP(F16,vScore,2)` may suit:

[image: SO21718670 example]

In the image, the area within the box is a range named vScore, here on the same sheet for the sake of the image.

Beware that the version of VLOOKUP above deliberately omits the fourth parameter in order to take advantage of inexact matching. In most cases this fourth parameter *is* required.

Answer (score 0):

You have your parentheses wrong. Corrected formula below:

```
=IF(OR(F16<=$H$4,F16>=$H$5),$H$2,IF(AND(F16>$I$4,F16=$J$4),$J$2))
```

Comment: Thank you! i knew it was something small